# Mule - Web Service Consumer takes a long (timeout) to read metadata

Tags: oracle, wsdl, timeout, mule, metadata

I am trying to read an Oracle WS using **Web Service Consumer component**.

When I put the URL it takes 30 seconds more or less to read all values (Port, Service..) automatically. But then, trying to read the operations Anypoint Studio returns a **timeout error (Reading metadata/schema definition)**.

In **SOAPUI** that takes **less than 15 seconds**. But also, the request in SOAPUI takes milliseconds and in Mule between 3-5 minutes.

How can I preload all schema definition or how can I log what is reading to take a lot of time?

Comment: Is it only the metadata operation that times out? Does the application executes quickly?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, were you able to figure something out?